# Что сказал датчик? Работа с байтами, расшифровка полученных данных. Python. Прошу помощи!

Tags: python, парсер, hex, byte, bytearray

## Что сказал датчик?

Датчики являются беспроводными, работают на батарейках до 7ми лет, поэтому они вынуждены передавать свои данные тщательно упакованными структурами.
Например четырьмя байтами информации датчик может передать информацию по 10 своим параметрам. Датчик отправляет пакет на хаб с данными (далее "пейлоад") "10FA0E00",
хаб должен расшифровать этот набор байтов и выдать уже обработанные данные по всем 10 параметрам, в таком виде:

```
{'field1': 'Low',
 'field2': '00',
 'field3': '01',
 'field4': '00',
 'field5': '00',
 'field6': '01',
 'field7': '00',
 'field8': 'Very High',
 'field9': '00',
 'field10': '00'}
```

### Структуру параметров в датчике можно представить следующим образом:

```
#Format settings - array [sett_byte1 as dict {bit: [size, 'field_name']}, sett_byte2, sett_byte3, sett_byte4]
device_settings = [{0: [3, 'field1'], 
                    3: [1, 'field2'],  
                    4: [1, 'field3'], 
                    5: [3, 'field4']}, 
                   {0: [1, 'field5'],  
                    1: [1, 'field6'], 
                    2: [1, 'field7'],  
                    3: [3, 'field8'], 
                   },
                   {0: [1, 'field9'], 
                    5: [1, 'field10']
                   },
                   {}
                  ]
```

Это список байтов (4), в которых каждому биту соответствует какой-то параметр (первый элемент в списке соответствующего бита). Некоторые параметры могут занимать больше одного бита, например field1, он занимает 3 бита, о чем говорит нулевой элемент списке соответствующего бита. Для параметров, которые в пейлоаде занимают больше 1 бита даны следующие переменные:

```
field1 = {'0': 'Low',
          '1': 'reserved',
          '2': 'reserved',
          '3': 'reserved',
          '4': 'Medium', 
          '5': 'reserved',
          '6': 'reserved',
          '7': 'High',  
          }
field4 = {'0': '00', 
          '1': '10',
          '2': '20',
          '3': '30',
          '4': '40',
          '5': '50',
          '6': '60',
          '7': '70',
          }
field8 = {'0': 'Very Low',
          '1': 'reserved',
          '2': 'Low',
          '3': 'reserved',
          '4': 'Medium',
          '5': 'High',
          '6': 'reserved',
          '7': 'Very High',
          }
```

Например, параметр field4, который занимает 3 бита, в битовой маске равен 011, что в десятичной системе измерения равно 3, из этого следует, что параметр field4 равен 30.

### Задание:

Написать функцию которая будет парсить пейлоад команды от датчика и возвращать значения всех параметров. Проверочные данные: пейлоад = "10FA0E00", функция должна вернуть структуру:

```
{'field1': 'Low',
 'field2': '00',
 'field3': '01',
 'field4': '00',
 'field5': '00',
 'field6': '01',
 'field7': '00',
 'field8': 'Very High',
 'field9': '00',
 'field10': '00',
}
```

#### Прошу помощи с этим заданием

*думал над его решением разными способами, например преобразовать полученные данные в виде* *`10FA0E00` шестнадцатеричного кода в двоичный и потом вытащить оттуда данные, никуда не* *продвинулся. Полученный двоичный вот:*

> `0011000100110000010001100100000100110000010001010011000000110000`

## Собственно как должен работать датчик

Данное изображение есть частичным решением и объяснением того как должен работать датчик и расшифровывать полученные данные в виде 10FA0E00: [image: Логика расшифровки 10FA0E00]

Comment: Дайте ваш нерабочий код, сообщите, в чем проблема?  Это линейно-последовательная скучноватая задача. Похоже более на фриланс, чем на учебную задачу.

Comment: Нет, это не фриланс, жаль что вы так подумали. Я получил это задание как тестовое, и не могу найти направления её решения, если вы в двух словах скажите мне алгоритм решения я буду очень благодарен!

Comment: как интересно. 1) А поясните мне, пожалуйста, как на выходе получается 'field2': '00', если field2 является четвертым битом последовательности "10FA0E00", где первые четыре бита = 1, то есть '0001'? 2) А как вы 4 байта в 64 бита преобразовали? Тоже интересно. 3) Это тестовое задание для устройства на работу?

Comment: 1) не могу сказать. 2)онлайн конвертором 3) да, работа подразумевает тестирование но на тестовое дали такое задание, вторым заданием нужно протестить это всё

Comment: Я вам скоро дам советы, а то и весь код - выяснилось, что я кое-что не знал, так что стало интересно. Но я вам не советую туда идти работать: 1) Вполне возможно, что они вам просто скинули свою работу на "выполнить за бесплатно". Не похоже это на тестовую задачу. 2) Если у них даже тестовый пример неверный, то что у них за подход?

Comment: 3) У вас знаний нет нужных, вам учиться нужно. Да и уровень интереса к задаче мал, а должен быть выше: а) вас не смущает, что у вас 4 байта (по определению 32 бита) вдруг превратились в 64 + вы даже после моего вопроса ничего не поменяли. б) У вас нет идей, как писать код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код с детальными комментариями - я поизучал некоторые возможности языка, которые не очень хорошо знал. Самое простое было решить "в лоб", но мне было интересно сделать для разнообразных структур, так что код достаточно адаптируемый.

Обратите внимание, что:

1. Значения при объявлении в`output`я установил в `test`, чтобы было видно, что выход реально обновлён.
2. 4 байта в коде записаны в правильной нотации (как они и должны прийти с устройства).
3. Тестовый пример, что вам дали, содержит неверный выход относительно логики, описанной вами в задании. `10FA0E00` эквивалентно 32  битам:

байт 1:`000 1 0 000`(откуда у вас появилось "параметр field4, который занимает 3 бита, в битовой маске равен 011" я не понимаю, так как ваш ответ был "не могу сказать." Тут он - 000, как видите.)

байт 2:`1 1 1 110 10` (последняя группа не используется)

байт 3:`0 0001 1 10` (вторая и четвертая группы не используются)

байт 4: `00000000` (не используется).

Возможно, ваши работодатели задание, торопясь, писали, а, возможно, вашу внимательность проверяют.
Код ниже работает относительно идеи, описанной выше. Если поймёте, что за ней стоит, и если это не ошибка, можете легко (надеюсь) модифицировать код. Есть у меня подозрение, что они начали считать с первого бита в двоичном представлении, не учтя, что три начальных 0 не отображаются. Впрочем, field4 это все равно не объясняет, разве что они ещё и обсчитались на один бит.

4. Запускать на Python 3.7 и выше. Используется поддержка упорядоченности словарей.

```
device_settings = [{0: [3, 'field1'],
                    3: [1, 'field2'],
                    4: [1, 'field3'],
                    5: [3, 'field4']},
                   {0: [1, 'field5'],
                    1: [1, 'field6'],
                    2: [1, 'field7'],
                    3: [3, 'field8'],
                   },
                   {0: [1, 'field9'],
                    5: [1, 'field10']
                   },
                   {}
                  ]

field1 = {'0': 'Low',
          '1': 'reserved',
          '2': 'reserved',
          '3': 'reserved',
          '4': 'Medium',
          '5': 'reserved',
          '6': 'reserved',
          '7': 'High',
          }
field4 = {'0': '00',
          '1': '10',
          '2': '20',
          '3': '30',
          '4': '40',
          '5': '50',
          '6': '60',
          '7': '70',
          }
field8 = {'0': 'Very Low',
          '1': 'reserved',
          '2': 'Low',
          '3': 'reserved',
          '4': 'Medium',
          '5': 'High',
          '6': 'reserved',
          '7': 'Very High',
          }

output= {'field1': 'test',
 'field2': 'test',
 'field3': 'test',
 'field4': 'test',
 'field5': 'test',
 'field6': 'test',
 'field7': 'test',
 'field8': 'test',
 'field9': 'test',
 'field10': 'test'}


# Переданные 4 байта в правильной записи
bytes = b'\x10\xFA\x0E\x00'
# Количество бит в записи
bits = 32
# Переданные 4 байта в десятичной форме для удобства оперирования в коде
bytes_to_int = int.from_bytes(bytes, byteorder='big')

# Последовательный проход по каждому байту в словаре. Использовать Python 3.7 и старше! 
for i in range (len(device_settings)):
    # Последовательный проход по битам во вложенных словарях.
    for key, value in device_settings[i].items():
        # Отсекаем правую часть, сдвигая вправо
        pre_res = bytes_to_int >> (bits - (i * 8 + key + value[0]))
        # Отсекаем левую часть, деля по модулю
        pre_res = pre_res % (2 ** value[0])
        # Берем значение из полей для параметров с длиной более 3 бит
        if value[1] == 'field1':
            result = field1[str(int(pre_res))]
        elif value[1] == 'field4':
            result = field4[str(int(pre_res))]
        elif value[1] == 'field8':
            result = field8[str(int(pre_res))]
        else:
            result = pre_res
        # Помещаем результат в выходную структуру
        output[value[1]] = result
print (output)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Возможно действительно проверяли на внимательность, я уточню у того кто мне его дал, почему оно такое. Вам отдельная благодарность за уделённое время. Если вас не затруднит, могли бы вы дать мне источник информации который изучали при решении этой задачи, хочу повысить свой уровень знаний

Comment: Весь источник - знание того, что такое словари (можете документацию почитать <https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/ispolzovanie-slovarej-dict-python/> + по всем ссылкам там), да запросы в Google по ситуации типа "примеры сдвига битов Python". Но у меня образование IT + я программистом был несколько лет. Самое же важное -  активно интересоваться всем непонятным и неизвестным и "лезть под капот". Например,  перевести байты в биты каким-то конвертером, не разбираясь - неправильно. Я так сам  "ручками" на бумажке перевел эти 4 байта в биты.

Comment: И да, поведайте потом, пожалуйста, чем обсуждение с работодателем завершилось. Что с правильностью теста + как оценили код?

Comment: приветствую! Получил фидбек, задание решено было не правильно, сказали что нужно было использовать fromhex или bytearray. Собственно поэтому есть ошибки в коде, какие именно мне не сказали. Также отправили репрезентацию(фото) как должен работать датчик. На мои вопросы почему сразу не отправили логику работы устройства чтобы не пришлось самому догадываться - не ответили. Благодарю вас за уделённое время и внимание!

Comment: Я вам сразу не советовал идти туда работать. Если они вам действительно сказали так, как у вас написано, то от вас просто отделались, получив бесплатно нужный код. Все, что делает `bytearray.fromhex()` - преобразует строку "10FA0E00" в b'\x10\xFA\x0E\x00'. Я эти `\x` вручную вписал в `bytes`. Так что "Собственно поэтому есть ошибки в коде, какие именно мне не сказали. " - ясно, что не сказали, так как их нет (расписать для проверки 4 байта на бумажке - не сложно), и с `bytearray.fromhex()` это никак не может быть связано.

Comment: Я могу вам отправить фото для ознакомления. В коментах нельзя прикреплять фото

Comment: Можете его прямо в вопрос включить в режиме редактирования. Это будет правильнее всего.

Comment: 1) Ясно. Они в словарях расписали все биты по порядку от 0, с чем я и начал работать, но считать в байте начинали от младшего бита к старшему. Право имеют, но я бы словарь в таком случае писал в таком же порядке, в не в инвертированном. Не зря я спрашивал, как получается ответ, в реальности такой вопрос Заказчику задаётся, и тот быстро отвечает.  2) К `bytearray.fromhex()` это, конечно, не относится. Его просто можно было добавить в код, чтобы строку преобразовать, если датчик действительно её выдаст.